# Building an automatic web crawler

Tags: web-crawler

I am building a web application crawler that's meant not only to find all the links or pages in a web application, but also perform all the allowed actions in the app (such as pushing buttons, filling forms, notice changes in the DOM even if they did not trigger a request etc.)

Basically, this is a kind of "browser simulator".

I find WebKit a good option to implement my crawler, since it has all the needed technology (Javascript engine, parsers, DOM manipulation, etc.) but it seems kind of an overkill being a fully featured browser.

Is there any toolkit you know that can provide the above functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

Answer (score 1):

I use webkit through PyQt to parse the JavaScript and then [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

if you're on mac, try fake app

http://www.fakeapp.com